# group by and agg and sort index

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

```
# I wrote this but it is geting error. can anyone explain
a =  reviews.groupby("price").agg(max).sort_index("points")

Note:- price and points are integers.

Error
```

No axis named price for object type DataFrame

```
# This is working fine but i didn't understand this?
b  = reviews.groupby('price')['points'].max().sort_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to use aggregation method, you must determine what aggregation function apply over what column. First code raise error because of you dont determine column for aggregation